# What is the best practice for reusing components across fragments with React/Relay/Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, relay

I'm making a web app with React, Relay (experimental), and Typescript and I'm having some issues re-using components with similar data/props across different fragments.

Let's say I have the following Relay query and main app component:

```
const query = graphql`
  query AppQuery {
    currentUser {
      ...HomePage_currentUser
      ...ProfilePage_currentUser
    }
  }
`;

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const appData = useLazyLoadQuery<AppQuery>(query, {});
 
 return (
   <>
    <HomePage currentUser={appData.currentUser}>
    <ProfilePage currentUser={appData.currentUser}>
   </>
 );
}
```

And the following page components:

```
interface HomePageProps {
  currentUser: HomePage_currentUser$key | null;
}

const currentUserFragment = graphql`
  fragment HomePage_currentUser on User {
    id
    profileImageUrl
    items {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;


export default function HomePage(props: HomePageProps): JSX.Element {
  const currentUser = useFragment(currentUserFragment, props.currentUser);

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      <ProfileIcon user={currentUser} >
      {/* ... */}
    </>
  )
}
```

```
interface ProfilePageProps {
  currentUser: ProfilePage_currentUser$key | null;
}

const currentUserFragment = graphql`
  fragment ProfilePage_currentUser on User {
    id
    profileImageUrl
    lastLoggedInTimestamp
  }
`;


export default function ProfilePage(props: ProfilePageProps): JSX.Element {
  const currentUser = useFragment(currentUserFragment, props.currentUser);

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      <ProfileIcon user={currentUser} >
      {/* ... */}
    </>
  )
}
```

And the following `ProfileIcon` component

```
interface ProfileIconProps {
  currentUser: ???
}

export default function ProfileIcon(props: ProfileIconProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={props.currentUser.profileImageUrl} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

My main question is regarding the type of the `currentUser` prop in the `ProfileIcon` component. It seems like there's no clean way to re-use the component for a `ProfilePage_currentUser` type and a `HomePage_currentUser` type despite the data being requested being incredibly similar and it clearly being compatible for the sake of this component.

Is there any recommended way to handle this other than something like this?

```
interface ProfileIconProps {
  currentUser: Omit<ProfilePage_currentUser, ' $refType'>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good practice in Relay to extract the data and pass it to a component as a prop manually. Instead you should have a fragment on the `ProfileIcon` component and let Relay takes care of passing the same data down to your component.

So you need to create a fragment in ProfileIcon component and query for `profileImageUrl` then add this fragment in both `HomePage_currentUser` and `ProfilePage_currentUser` fragments and relay will take care of the rest for you.

```
interface ProfileIconProps {
  currentUser: ProfileIcon_currentUser$key | null;
}

const currentUserFragment = graphql`
  fragment ProfileIcon_currentUser on User {
    profileImageUrl
  }
`;


export default function ProfileIcon(props: ProfileIconProps): JSX.Element {
  const currentUser = useFragment(currentUserFragment, props.currentUser);

  return (
    <div>
     <img src={props.currentUser.profileImageUrl} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In HomePage component add `ProfileIcon_currentUser` fragment

```
const currentUserFragment = graphql`
 fragment HomePage_currentUser on User {
    id
    items {
      id
      name
    }
    ...ProfileIcon_currentUser
 }
```

`;

In ProfilePage component add `ProfileIcon_currentUser` fragment

```
 const currentUserFragment = graphql`
  fragment ProfilePage_currentUser on User {
    id
    lastLoggedInTimestamp
    ...ProfileIcon_currentUser
  }
`;
```

One of the advantage of using this pattern is that if you have a mutation on User somewhere else (even not within the same react node tree hierarchy) and let's say you
change the `profileImageUrl` then the ProfileIcon will receive the new `profileImageUrl` automatically without you passing around a new value of profileImageUrl. In fact, Relay store will be updated with the new value on mutation payload and as soon as as there is a new update in store, it will pass that data to any components that are using that data.